# Simulink Arduino Deploy to Hardware

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, simulink, arduino-uno

When Deploying to Hardware, a simple Simulink program of reading a analog signal, following error is seen. Using Win10 with Matlab 2015a (64bit).

```
Code Generation  1
    Elapsed: 0.161 sec

     ### Generating code into build folder: C:\Users\Sujata Jaggi\Desktop\Final Semester\EXOSKELETON\Electronics\Code\analogread_grt_rtw

     ### Build procedure for model: 'analogread' aborted due to an error.

     Unable to open the database C:\Users\Sujata Jaggi\Desktop\Final Semester\EXOSKELETON\Electronics\Code\slprj\grt\_sharedutils\shared_file.dmr. (unable to open database file)
```

Comment: Could be the spaces in the file path; easy to move it to check